# java java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while adding property to apache jena

Tags: java, apache, error-handling

Hi I have this piece of code which is giving me trouble:

```
StmtIterator iter2 = model.listStatements(new SimpleSelector(null, FOAF.family_name, (RDFNode) null) {
            public boolean selects(Statement s) {
                // return the statements whose object equal to the required place
                return s.getString().toLowerCase().equals(latin.toLowerCase());
            }
        });
        if (iter2.hasNext()) {
            while (iter2.hasNext()) {
                Statement s = iter2.nextStatement();
                // s.getSubject().addProperty(FOAF.family_name, maltese, "mt");
            }
        }
```

The commented line is the line throwing the exception. Any idea why this is happening?

This is the whole error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at com.hp.hpl.jena.mem.HashCommon$BasicKeyIterator.hasNext(HashCommon.java:354)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.NiceIterator$1.hasNext(NiceIterator.java:103)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.hasNext(WrappedIterator.java:90)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.Map1Iterator.hasNext(Map1Iterator.java:48)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.hasNext(WrappedIterator.java:90)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.hasNext(WrappedIterator.java:90)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.FilterIterator.hasNext(FilterIterator.java:54)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.hasNext(WrappedIterator.java:90)
at NotarialArchivesTurtle.main(NotarialArchivesTurtle.java:643)
```

The problem seems to be caused because I am adding a property the same as the one I was searching for ie: family_name

Comment: Can you post a full running code sample?

Comment: `s` keeps a reference to the Iterator you are iterating on. When you try to add a property on it, you are actually trying to modify the iterator that you are using. Try deep-cloning `s` with `.clone()` and add the property there.

Comment: I don't think that s.clone() is possible...I thought that something like that is happening but didn't find a way around it

Comment: @Joe124 You can try and take a look here on how to get a deep-copy: https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy